# Enviar informações de um Data grid Viwer para banco de dados sql

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, foreach

Estou montando um formulário de pedidos utilizando **c#**.

O problema é que quando tento enviar os produtos que estão listados no Data Grid Viewer para o banco de dados, o programa lê apenas a linha em que o cursor está.

Sei que preciso de um `foreach` para percorrer todas as colunas e linhas, mas como posso montar esta estrutura do `foreach`?

Comment: coloque o código que ja tens pronto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou dar mais informações e posta o código que vc já tentou. Supondo que o banco seja o `SQlServer`, e sua grid tenha 4 colunas, ficaria assim:

Não sei quais os tipo de dados usado por vc, então atente-se aos campos. O conteúdo das células terão o tipo de retorno `object`.

```
void AddPedidos()
{
   string sqlQuery;
   string strConexao = "Seu caminho para o banco";

   try
   {
      SqlConnection Conexao = new SqlConnection(strConexao);
      Conexao.Open();

      foreach (DataGridViewRow linha in dgvProdutos.Rows)
      {
         qlQuery = $"INSERT INTO Pedidos(ID, Emissao, ProdutoID, Quantidade) VALUES({linha.Cells[0].Value}, {linha.Cells[2].Value}, {linha.Cells[3].Value}, {linha.Cells[4].Value})";

         SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, Conexao);
         Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       Conexao.Close();
   }
   catch (SqlException erro)
   {
      MessageBox.Show($"Ocorreu um erro: {erro.Message}");
   }        
}
```

Você pode usar o `ForEach`para percorrer todas as linhas na Grid.
O `dgvProdutos` é a DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

```
  void AddPedidos(DataGridView dgvPedido)
  {

   for(int i=0;i<dgvPedido.rowcount;i++){

    string pos0=dgvPedido[0,i].value.ToString();
    string pos1=dgvPedido[1,i].value.ToString();

    //insira o código para invaiar os dados na base de dados

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         //Segue um exemplo usando o entityframework: 
                    ExtratoCentroCusto centroCusto = new ExtratoCentroCusto();
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in GridRateio.Rows)
                    {
                        centroCusto.Valor = Convert.ToDecimal(dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                        centroCusto.IdPlanoConta = int.Parse(dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                        centroCusto.PlanoConta = dr.Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString(); //pegando o valor da celula
                        db.ExtratoCentroCusto.Add(centroCusto);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
```